# Values are not getting inserted in a numpy 2d array

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, numpy

I am trying to normalize each row in a numpy 2d array. But when I am trying to use the insert function of the numpy the values are not getting inserted.

This is my code:

```
import numpy as np
def minmax_norm(arr):
    y = np.zeros([arr.shape[0],arr.shape[1]])
    for i in range(0,arr.shape[0]):
        sample = arr[i:i+1][0]
        minimum = min(sample)
        maximum = max(sample)
        deno = maximum - minimum
        list2 = []
        for i in sample:
            list2.append(((i-minimum) / deno))
        arr2 = np.array(list2)  
        np.insert(y,i,arr2,0) #values should be inserted here 
    return y

if __name__ == "__main__":
    x = np.array([[0, 1, 2], [1, 2, 0], [2, 1, 2], [3, 2, 0]])
    print(x)
    arr = minmax_norm(x)
    print (arr)
```

Can anyone please tell me why the values are not getting inserted?

Comment: Not an in-place operation. So, assign it back. Seriously need a canonical Q&A to close these questions.

Comment: See [the docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.insert.html). "Note that _insert does not occur in place_"

Comment: y = np.zeros([4,4]);
print(y);
list1 = [0,1,2,5];
arr = np.array(list1);
np.insert(y,3,arr,0) #This works perfectly